# How high is too high to air fry a hard boiled egg?

Tags: hard-boiled-eggs, air-frying

Everything I see says to air fry your eggs at around 270 degrees. Why not 400 at shorter time? Will this cause problems?

I know I could try, but hoping someone else already has so I don't have to clean up an explosion in case that would happen. :)

Comment: Are we talking a hard-boiled egg, or a raw egg?

Comment: @FuzzyChef I assume (especially given the worry about egg explosion) the question is about bringing an egg from raw to a hard-boiled state using an air fryer.

Comment: Oh, no.  Hard-boiled eggs explode pretty impressively if you fry them in high heat.  I have an apron that will never be truly clean again to prove it.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Sorry for the confusion, I am talking about "hard boiling" a raw egg. But then I guess I'm not really boiling it so that's not quite correct either, lol. And yes, I've tried to heat (already) hard boiled eggs in the microwave before and learned the hard way how long is too long!

Comment: So roasting an egg?  In the shell?  Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about roasting eggs in the shell in your air fryer, rather than frying them.

All recipes I found for doing so ([example](https://www.wholesomeyum.com/perfect-baked-hard-boiled-eggs-in-the-oven/)) limit the heat to 325F/160C.  Above that, the [eggs will reportedly explode](https://www.myrecipes.com/how-to/cooking-questions/roast-egg-passover-seder).  The reason for the even lower temperature limit on the air fryer is probably because, with its rapid convection, the air fryer heats the eggs even faster.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if my Air Fryer should more accurately be called an Air Roaster, given that it uses trays rather than a basket? Never thought about it before. I suppose really it should just be called a convection toaster oven, lol.